# Rounding error in Mysql 5.5+?

Tags: mysql, rounding

I'm having a weird rounding problem.

Here is the setup (MySQL5.5 Percona; same in Mysql 5.7 CE):

```
CREATE TABLE `roundingtest` (
`RT_Double` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`RT_Float` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`RT_Decimal` DECIMAL(10,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now enter in each of the 3 fields "1.785".

Now execute this query:

```
SELECT
1.785, ROUND(1.785, 2),
RT_Double, ROUND(RT_Double, 2),
RT_Float, ROUND(RT_Float, 2),
RT_Decimal, ROUND(RT_Decimal, 2)
FROM roundingtest
```

Here are the results:
[image: rounding 2]

If you round to one decimal place:
[image: rounding 1]

Someone please explain this behavior...

It's only correct with the DECIMAL field, even with only 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL Rounding Behaviour](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-rounding.html):

> For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the “round to nearest even” rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even integer.

This means that floating point numbers may be rounded towards the nearest even integer.  `DECIMAL` numbers are considered exact, so fractional parts of 0.5 or more are rounded up.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably due to the way floating points are saved on a computer, not being completely accurate (due to being saved in base 2, not base 10).  If 1.785 is saved as 1.784998, it would round down.  If it saved as 1.785001, it would round up.